# Analyzing image using Hilbert-curve

Tags: c#, graphics

I would like to visit each pixel of an image using the "path" of the Hilbert-curve. I've found a recursive implementation of the Hilbert-cuve [here](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/07/draw-a-hilbert-curve-fractal-in-c/), but I don't know how to apply this on an image.
Is it important to have a picture which width and height are equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but make sure the curve is adaptive or is bigger than the image. Adaptive curve is very complicated.

Comment: @user234780:Adaptive curve is very complicated. Try a bigger curve.

Comment: Ok, I'll try a bigger one, but I still don't know how to set the Hilbert curve's size. The algorithm I linked uses the **depth** value to set the depth of the recursion. I also need a value which sets that the size will be e.g.: 500 x 500px.

Comment: @user234780:Translate the coordinate to a binary and interleave. Its much easier. If you don't want try a gray code it can help to find it. You can also try a brute force with a table. Search for nick hilbert spatial index quadtree. L-systems is just for joy.

Comment: @user234780:The link you mentioned and depth value means at each depth the curve is 4 times bigger. So its power of 2.

Comment: @user234780:If my answer is helpful consider to accept or upvote it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would like to revive this and point out that "adaptive" curve is not complicated at all -- see my answer.

Comment: @jcerveny: Can you do the reverse? I read your answer and github but I didn't understand. Could you explain in simpler terms? Care to elaborate?

Comment: Maybe we each mean something else by "adaptive", but my impression was that the OP needs to generate a Hilbert-like curve in a grid of arbitrary dimensions (like an image). I haven't seen a simple algorithm for that anywhere so I posted my solution.

Comment: No, I already knew some of the presented algorithm I just didn't understand how your algorithm works.

Comment: @Gigamegs: I have edited the answer and added a more detailed description of the algorithm in the github readme.

Comment: @jcervenry: Ok. thank you. I think I understood now. Do you mean you just draw a straight line when it's not  a power of 2? Interesting. Can you do the reverse? Hilbert-index to nd coordinate? What about an iterative algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an algorithm that generates a Hilbert-like curve for a non-square array.

The idea is to recursively apply a Hilbert-like template but avoid odd sizes when halving the domain dimensions. If the dimensions happen to be powers of two, the classic Hilbert curve is generated.

```
def gilbert2d(x, y, ax, ay, bx, by):
    """
    Generalized Hilbert ('gilbert') space-filling curve for arbitrary-sized
    2D rectangular grids.
    """

    w = abs(ax + ay)
    h = abs(bx + by)

    (dax, day) = (sgn(ax), sgn(ay)) # unit major direction
    (dbx, dby) = (sgn(bx), sgn(by)) # unit orthogonal direction

    if h == 1:
        # trivial row fill
        for i in range(0, w):
            print x, y
            (x, y) = (x + dax, y + day)
        return

    if w == 1:
        # trivial column fill
        for i in range(0, h):
            print x, y
            (x, y) = (x + dbx, y + dby)
        return

    (ax2, ay2) = (ax/2, ay/2)
    (bx2, by2) = (bx/2, by/2)

    w2 = abs(ax2 + ay2)
    h2 = abs(bx2 + by2)

    if 2*w > 3*h:
        if (w2 % 2) and (w > 2):
            # prefer even steps
            (ax2, ay2) = (ax2 + dax, ay2 + day)

        # long case: split in two parts only
        gilbert2d(x, y, ax2, ay2, bx, by)
        gilbert2d(x+ax2, y+ay2, ax-ax2, ay-ay2, bx, by)

    else:
        if (h2 % 2) and (h > 2):
            # prefer even steps
            (bx2, by2) = (bx2 + dbx, by2 + dby)

        # standard case: one step up, one long horizontal, one step down
        gilbert2d(x, y, bx2, by2, ax2, ay2)
        gilbert2d(x+bx2, y+by2, ax, ay, bx-bx2, by-by2)
        gilbert2d(x+(ax-dax)+(bx2-dbx), y+(ay-day)+(by2-dby),
                 -bx2, -by2, -(ax-ax2), -(ay-ay2))
```

More information, examples, etc., available here: https://github.com/jakubcerveny/gilbert